# Post a value from php page to the same page doesn't work

Tags: php, html, file, post

I write a php code to save the input posted value, it send to the same page. The matter is here nothing will posted.
The code is Bellow:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="../page1.php" id="form1">
paid code: 
 <input id="pcode" type="text" />
 <input type="submit" />
 <?php
 if(empty($_POST["pcode"])){
    echo "<br/> This Field Cannot Be Empty";
 }
 else{

$num = $_POST["pcode"];

# To get a shorter version of the hash, just use substr
$hash = substr(md5($num), 0, 10);
echo $hash;
file_put_contents("code.txt",  $hash ."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
</form>
```

It's page1.php. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: keep action empty... nothing to write in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="../page1.php" id="form1">
<input id="pcode" type="text" />
```

to:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
<input id="pcode" name='pcode' type='text' />
```

It would work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from the lack of `name` assigned to the text element - an ID attribute is NOT sent in the POST request. Also - you can simply omit the form `action` in order to get the form to post to itself.

```
<form method='post'>
    paid code: 

    <input name='pcode' type='text' />
    <input type='submit' />

    <?php
        if( empty( $_POST['pcode'] ) ){
            echo '<br/> This Field Cannot Be Empty';
        } else{

            $num = $_POST['pcode'];

            # To get a shorter version of the hash, just use substr
            $hash = substr(md5($num), 0, 10);
            echo $hash;
            file_put_contents('code.txt',  $hash .'\r\n', FILE_APPEND);
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You change this line,

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="../page1.php" id="form1">
```

To

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `action="../page1.php"`, use `action="page1.php"` or `action=""`